# Recursive function in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE players
(
    winner            CHARACTER VARYING(50) NOT NULL ,
    successor              CHARACTER VARYING(50) NOT NULL ,
    data           NUMERIC(6,2) NOT NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT pk_win_succ PRIMARY KEY (winner, successor)
);
```

The data:

```
  INSERT INTO players VALUES
  ('Helen','Sharon',12),
  ('Claudia','Steffi',35),
  ('Sharon','Penny',5),
  ('Meg','Claudia',21),
  ('Penny','Meg',3)
  ('Steffi','Helen',230);
```

And what I need to do is a SQL query that gives me the different possible combinations between the players.

If I chose the player Sharon as an initial and the player Meg as final, the result of the query should be:

```
Initial | Final | List of winners | Total Data | Number of Winners |
Sharon | Meg | Sharon - Penny - Meg | 8 | 3
```

If I chose the player Claudia as an initial and the player Sharon as final, the result of the query should be:

```
Initial | Final | List of winners | Total Data | Number of Winners |
Claudia | Sharon | Claudia - Steffi - Helen - Sharon | 277 | 4
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for a 'chain' from one player to another. Is this some kind of [6 degrees of separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_degrees_of_separation)? If so, your best friend is a graph database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A chain from Sharon to Meg can be built with a recursive query:

```
 WITH RECURSIVE chain(winner, successor, data, active) AS (
   SELECT winner, successor, data, true
     FROM players
     WHERE winner = 'Sharon'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT p.winner, p.successor, p.data
         ,CASE WHEN p.successor = 'Meg' OR NOT c.active THEN false ELSE true END
     FROM players p
     JOIN chain c ON (p.winner = c.successor AND c.active)
 )
 SELECT * FROM chain
```

Result:

```
Sharon;Penny;5.00;t
Penny;Meg;3.00;f
```

Then the result set can be aggregated into the desired format:

```
 WITH RECURSIVE chain(winner, successor, data, active) AS (
   SELECT winner, successor, data, true
     FROM players
     WHERE winner = 'Sharon'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT p.winner, p.successor, p.data
         ,CASE WHEN p.successor = 'Meg' OR NOT c.active THEN false ELSE true END
     FROM players p
     JOIN chain c ON (p.winner = c.successor AND c.active)
 )
 SELECT 'Sharon' AS Initial
       ,'Meg' AS Final
       ,'Sharon - ' || string_agg(successor, ' - ') AS Winners
       ,sum(data) AS Total
       ,count(*) + 1 AS WinnerCount
   FROM chain
```

Or parameterized:

```
PREPARE plan(text, text) AS

 WITH RECURSIVE chain(winner, successor, data, active) AS (
   SELECT winner, successor, data, true
     FROM players
     WHERE winner = $1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT p.winner, p.successor, p.data
         ,CASE WHEN p.successor = $2 OR NOT c.active THEN false ELSE true END
     FROM players p
     JOIN chain c ON (p.winner = c.successor AND c.active)
)
SELECT $1 AS Initial
      ,$2 AS Final
      ,$1 || ' - ' || string_agg(successor, ' - ') AS Winners
      ,sum(data) AS Total
      ,count(*) + 1 AS WinnerCount
  FROM chain
;

EXECUTE plan('Sharon', 'Meg');

EXECUTE plan('Claudia', 'Sharon');
```